# Are dandelions flowers or weeds?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I picked a dandelion this morning, but rather than disappear it went into my inventory. So are they considered flowers or weeds?

If I just leave them be, will they lower my town's happiness levels? Can they be bred to make different colors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From history, [Dandelions are weeds that do not negatively affect town happiness](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Dandelion_Puff) and will eventually mature into dandelion puffs which can be blown away.

So they're weeds, though you don't necessarily have to pull them. You can even transplant them if you pick them before they turn into puffs. A hint to their weedy nature is that they take many more attempts to trample. 3 tramples will kill a flower, it takes more like 8 to kill a dandelion.